# why this toast shows up when it should not?

Tags: java, android, class, methods, toast

**Hello**

i have a method that  verificate whether a phone number or an email is already exists in the database , if so user will get a toast says its already registred and will go back to signUp activity if not it will go on with the code,

```
public class VerficatePhone extends AppCompatActivity {
private String mVerficationId,phoneNumber,sentCode;
private User user;
private EditText phoneCodeEditText;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResend;
private Button activate;
private TextView backToSignupText;
private ProgressBar pBar;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference reff;
private boolean executed =false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verficate_phone);

    phoneCodeEditText=findViewById(R.id.verificationEditText);
    activate=findViewById(R.id.activate);
    backToSignupText=findViewById(R.id.backToSignupText);
    pBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");


    //getting the user that has been sent from the sign up Activity and the phone number
    if(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userFromSignUp")!=null)
    {
        user=(User)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userFromSignUp");
        phoneNumber=user.getPhoneNumber();

    }
    else
    {
        phoneNumber="000";
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(!executed)
    {
        checkPhoneNumIfExists(user);
        executed =true;
    }

    sendCode(phoneNumber);
}
```

my  checkPhoneNumIfExists method is like this

```
 private void checkPhoneNumIfExists (final User currentUser)
{
    Log.i("checkPhoneNumIfExists method","processing");
     FirebaseDatabase fDb=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference dbRef=fDb.getReference();
        dbRef.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children=dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                for(DataSnapshot child:children)
                {
                    if(currentUser!=null && child!=null)
                    {
                        User user= child.getValue(User.class);
                        if(user!=null && !user.getPhoneNumber().isEmpty())
                        {
                            if(currentUser.getPhoneNumber().equals(user.getPhoneNumber()) || currentUser.geteMail().equals(user.geteMail()))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(VerficatePhone.this,"already registred",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i =new Intent(VerficatePhone.this,signUpActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("userFromVerificate",currentUser);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();



                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    executed =true;

}
```

so here is the problem , when the user is not registred its go on with the code and excute sendCode method in onCreate method which will open a new activity ,but whenever its open the new activity from sendCode method the toast of checkPhoneNumIfExists method it shows up.

**so why that would happen??**

Comment: You need to clarify your question, it is hard to understand what you are asking about besides that you have a bug in your code. I don't understand what your code is doing at all? I have no understanding of how I can test it locally to reproduce the error?

In function: onCreate() where is "executed" defined?

You define "executed" in checkPhoneNumIfExists() but you never return the value? Which you say that you shouldn't cause function is void

Comment: i've modified the code , hope its will make it more clear , my code is working fine but the toast of checkPhoneNumIfExists its shows up even thought user is not registered, thank you for your patience, i did not put all the class beacause its pretty long

Comment: The `onDataChange()` callback is asynchronous. Your `executed=true` and `sendCode()` are likely to run before `onDataChange()` returns. You should make sure that anything you need from that callback is triggered when it returns or afterward.

Comment: Thank you Sammy, so can I just override onCallback method? Or maybe you can show me how to do it the best way please

Answer (score 0):

The `onDataChange()` is an asynchronous callback. Any data or function that relies upon it should be accessed or triggered from within the callback.

Since it looks like you're not intending to run the database check every time, I would suggest looking into SharedPreferences to persist the variable if you leave and return to the activity. You can store the value of `executed` when your `onDataChange()` executes and retrieve the value in `onCreate()` before your if statement.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ...

    // If you're using SharedPreferences, retrieve the value here

    if(!executed){
        checkDb(user)
    }else{
        // I'm assuming you only want to send the code when executed is true
        // which means that, for this approach, you should call sendCode()
        // again inside of your onDataChange()
        sendCode(phoneNum);
    }
}

private void checkDb(final User currentUser){
    // ...

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                // do something with the data
                // ...
            }

            // This is where you can set the value of a variable 
            // or execute a function that relies upon the data of the callback. 

            // If you're using SharedPreferences, you would store the value here.

            // You may want to call sendCode() again here
        }
    });
}
```

You can find out about SharedPreferences by visiting https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences